# how to implement breadcrumbs in angular components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am trying to implement breadcrumb in angular 1.6 using components.
i have around 10 components inside a view(container component) which have different links and one main component which actually displays the data (say a word document) rest are all links to recommended documents.

my hierarchy is Home> Search >ShowAllResults > view

and i want breadcrumbs like Home > {keywords searched} > {categroy of search} > {doc name} .

my problem is that i cannot use    `<bread-crumb></bread-crumb>` globally because of my website design. i have to call it on every page. 
so what would be the best way to retain this hierarchy so that i get a neat and nice navigations?

My idea is to use localstorage as storage medium and render the data in  `<bread-crumb></bread-crumb>` . and use $destroy to remove the recent url/state

the issue with this approach is the `$destroy` will execute first. fetch the data from localstorage and modify breadcrumb, but before that my insertion in localstorage will happen. or i think so. so this mess is causing the breadcrumb to break the formation. also i dont know how to handel browser back

Comment: What is `<bread-crumb></bread-crumb>`? And why you cant get hold keyword search and category search in `$stateParams`?

Comment: no its a component created for rendering and displaying breadcrumb @Leguest

Comment: Hello. How about https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-breadcrumbs ?

Comment: @СергейТертичный thanks a lot. this will sure help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some investigation and research i found https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-breadcrumbs to be the best solution. its already implemented in the best way.